# You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs

Tags: android

I have an existing app that has been on the market for over a year and has been through many upgrades. Recently I changed the way I built my app, making it into a library so that it would be easier to make multiple variations of the app - free/paid/alternative markets etc. etc. Now I've made some graphical changes so wish to update my standard version that is on google play, but upon uploading I get the following message:

```
 Upload failed

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

[  ]

and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):

[ SHA1: E5:FC:E7:30:F4:B2:91:16:94:3B:31:6D:B0:CA:FA:D4:A1:D8:5E:12 ]
```

So it looks like my current apk has no fingerprint (whatever that is) at all. How could that be?

**EDIT:** I have seen similar questions on SO, but the answers either did not apply, or I didn't understand how to implement the solutions.

**EDIT:** I have just found a backup of my original keystore file and used that when exporting my project. But google gave exactly the same error. So to recap, I have my original keystore file, I used the same alias, the same pair of passwords... and still have the same error.

Comment: You need to sign the new APK with the same certificate that you originally used to sign the first APK you uploaded.

Comment: Signed your apk with the same key from the one you signed your apk which is published in the play store.

Comment: I am confused about the meaning of the words "certificate", "key" and "keystore"... I get the feeling that they are used interchangeably and are in fact one and the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#marketupgrade):

> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the element of the manifest file. Also, the package name must be the same and the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.