# (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Tags: android

google autoplaces suggesion return this error. what is the meaning and solution? help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808490/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-is-signed-with-a-different-certificate-to-your-previous)

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation : 
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#marketupgrade

Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the element of the manifest file. Also, the package name must be the same and the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost the key, then you won't be able to update it. Pull your old app from playstore, change its name to anything, then upload the new apk.